# Jupyterlab "Error: 500 (Internal Server Error)"... trying to add extensions

Tags: node.js, terminal, pip, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I'm new to jupyterlab so I'm not sure if this is a noob thing. I had extensions disabled and once I enable them I tried installing the jupyterlab-spreadsheet extension. At first it was giving me an error that I needed node.js or npm installed. However, I do have them both So I decided to go to my terminal and simply install it that way. After what it looked like it did the job. I went to the extensions on Jupyterlab only to now find this

"Error: 500 (Internal Server Error)"

What am I doing wrong? I also have pip3 and Anaconda on my Macbook.

Comment: Please add the full logs from your `jupyter lab --debug`.

Comment: I apologize. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking? I activated my conda environment and then opened up jupyter lab. Afterwards I clicked on extensions and clicked enabled. Next I searched for the spreadsheet extension. It allowed me to download but it said I needed to rebuild. I saved afterwards and restarted. Long story short I dont know why but it seems to be working now..